# How to format int64 to upper case hex in Vala?

Tags: string, hex, printf, vala

The following example does not compile

```cs
    public static int main (string[] args) {
        var now = new GLib.DateTime.now_utc();
        int64 val = now.to_unix();
        print ("%" + int64.FORMAT + "\n", val);
        print ("%X\n", val);  // ERROR
        return 0;
    }
```

There is a int64 format string for decimal representation but none for hex (See [Valadoc](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/int64.FORMAT_MODIFIER.html)). The `%X` does also not work. How do I get upper case hex formatting for a int64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a type error: Argument 2: Cannot convert from `int64` to `uint`

`print` uses the [printf format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string) and accepts the long long type, which is specified as at least 64 bits. You can use `%llX` to print out an int64 as upper case hexadecimal.

Working example:

```
void main () {
    var now = new GLib.DateTime.now_utc();
    int64 val = now.to_unix();
    print ("%" + int64.FORMAT + "\n", val);
    print ("%llX\n", val);
}
```

Comment: That works but still throws a warning `warning: format ‘%llX’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘gint64’ {aka ‘long int’} [-Wformat=]
  g_print ("%llX\n", val);`

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: It is for Ubuntu/elementary OS.

Comment: I'm not getting a warning with Fedora. I had a quick look in [gtypes.h](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/master/glib/gtypes.h) for `gint64`, but didn't get far. It will have something to do with how the platform defines a `long`. You can try casting to `long`, e.g. `print ("%lX\n", (long)val);`. That works also for me, but I'm not sure of the authoritative, cross platform, solution

Comment: It's acceptable in my case as there is no loss in precision with the cast. I am currently developing on Ubuntu LTS, maybe it's just too old. It's the minimal Version I want to support. Thank you for your effort.